# What Does The Following Java Code Do

Tags: java

What does the following piece of java code do?

```
public static void dontknow(int[] a){
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        for (int j = a.length-1; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (a[j-1] > a[j])
            { 
                int T = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = a[j];
                a[j] = T;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start from the innermost block and work your way out. This should give you some idea of what sort of algorithm it is. ;-)

Comment: `while(dontUnderstand()) { testAndDebug(); }`

Comment: so would i start from the if statement? I still dont fully understand it as i dont quite know where the values come from

Comment: what values? the only thing ambiguous here is the content of the Int array `a`. The rest is loop index counters.

Comment: you should understand it step by step.because next time you will see different code

Comment: should i start from the inner if statement i think this is what is confusing me

Comment: there is lot of books on internet .take a one book and study ..that don't take much time

Comment: Just because one understands each individual line of code doesn't mean one will understand what the algorithm as a whole does or even the purpose of a given line.  SO has become really unhelpful and not welcoming to new users. I'm sorry you received such a response to your first question, @amb101293...I assure you that SO has helpful and patient users as well.

Comment: could someone tell me what the functional purpose of this code does and if possible a set of test cases so i could try to test it to see if the output that i get is the same

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather weird implementation of [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) to sort the int array contents by size. Albeit a rather stupid one as it doesn't stop when the array is sorted, but always makes the max. number of passes (`a.length` iterations).

Comment: so what is the functional purpose of the piece of code

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Bubble Sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It sorts the array in a efficient way.

Comment: Strike the "efficient". Bubblesort is rather inefficient and this one especially, as it could detect a perfect sort way earlier than after `a.length` iterations.